# How to undo changes made in InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have done a stupid mistake and made some changes in my Item that I edited in InfoPath. And I clicked at the and publish to the server.

How can I now undo those changes? I was looking everywhere but some how I can not find a thing. I am using SharePoint Designer 2013

Comment: Do you still have the form open in InfoPath? If you do you should be able to undo the changes (some of them) using ctrl + z.

Comment: @Christoffer No I do not

Comment: Was it a custom form or a list form?

Comment: @Christoffer When I select Desgine Froms in InfoPath I see it as a List